# How to keep margin in both sides of a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I made a image slider for my website. I want 98px margin in both right and left sides of it so that the slider seems to be middle in the webpage. How to do that?

Now I know:

**margin-left:98px; 
margin-right:98px;** can keep 98px margin in both sides. But in my case it doesn't work.

main.php file:

```
    </div>
<div id="gallery">
<!--code for slider begins-->
<div id="slide_frame_setup">
<p id="slider_paragraph">The slider contains my recently taken photos.
To visit my huge collection of photography please visit 
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/100402704740320621129/photos">External Photo Gallery</a></p>
<br />
<br />
<div id="slider_width">
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="1.jpg" />

        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

.CSS file:

```
.slides {
    padding: 0;

    width: 750px;
    height: 420px;

    display: block;

    margin: 0 auto;

    position: relative;


}

.slides *{
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;

}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block;


 }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 70px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

      opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: -5px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~.nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~.nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~.nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~.nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~.n
av-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~.nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#slider_paragraph{
text-align:center;

font-family:Tahoma;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3rgef73/)

Comment: Can you post your code in fiddle with some images.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you can try something like this:

```
.slide{
    width: Calc(100% - 196px); /*196px means both sides (left 98px and right 98px)*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i solved it:  .slide img {

    width: 121.5%;
    height:100%;
 }

Comment: Ok, It'll keep the proportion when resizing the page ;)